# Sikuli in Jython vs Sikuli in Java, is there any difference?

Tags: java, jython, sikuli

I currently have some automation written in Sikuli at the Jython layer, but I started to wonder if it was better to do this at the Java level?

The Scripts are becomming more and more important. So I'm wondering if I gain speed or stability if written at the Java layer?

Anyone with experince with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm working on a middle-sized project with sikuli, too and asked myself the same question some time ago. 
I think the answer to this question depends on your personal liking and skills. 
I'm really happy with Python because of the great flexibility of the language. On the other hand, I now have problems finding a professional IDE for jython. There are not many very good solutions for this unfortunately.

I don't think there are any big speed/stability differences because all the time taking image recognition stuff happens in the libCV module anyway and that is written in C or C++ so this is not dependent as far as I know.

Hope to have helped you a little and good look with sikuli.. I know it can be a little bitchy sometimes :D

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a programming expert but in my experience Sikuli's speed in most cases was limited only by the speed of the application or system under test (AUT / SUT) - means in most cases Sikuli had to wait for the application and not vise versa. Test execution was not slowed down by Sikuli, it was as fast as the application allowed it to be.

A great tool chain to use Sikuli in mid-sized or even big-sized projects is: Sikuli + [Robot Framework](http://robotframework.org/) + IntelliJ IDEA 14 (Community Edition) with Python and Robot Framework plugins. For an example have a look at this [Sikuli-and-Robot-Framework_How-To](https://github.com/Tset-Noitamotua/Sikuli-and-Robot-Framework-Integration).